# Setting a Git alias which uses TR to translate backslash into forward slash

Tags: git, git-config, git-alias

I am trying to set up a `Git` alias which has to convert a backslash to a forward slash to pass it later to `filter-branch` command (the need arises since I use `Posh` and will pass `DOS` based file path as a parameter).

So I have this alias:

```
echo-test = "!f() { path=$(echo $1 | tr '\\' '/'); echo $path; }; f"
```

But I get this error:

> tr: warning: an unescaped backslash at end of string is not portable

I tried writing `tr '\\\\' '/'` inside, thinking that `Git` simply escapes the `\` and `bash` gets a single `\`, but I get the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried 8 backslashes `'\\\\\\\\'`?

Comment: @kennytm, holy crap, I thought you were teasing me, but it worked! So what is happening under the hood? 3 escapes?

Comment: Yeah so there are definitely 3 escapes (once in `tr`), not sure above the other two, probably once in the alias definition and once in bash.

Comment: @kennytm, nice catch, thanks. You can submit an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: I need to dig out the reference first :). All the above are just guessing.

Comment: Since it doesn't appear to have anything to do with Git, you'd be better off making this as a shell alias or program and avoid Git's weird escaping. Alternatively, write the function in another file and `source` it into the Git alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write 8 backslashes here, because the string will be unescaped three times.

```
echo-test = "!f() { path=$(echo $1 | tr '\\\\\\\\' '/'); echo $path; }; f"
```

1. The first doubling is due to `tr` as OP have already used.
2. The second doubling is due to the [format of `.gitconfig`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_syntax)

   > Inside double quotes, double quote `"` and backslash `\` characters must be escaped: use `\"` for `"` and `\\` for `\`.
3. The third doubling is due to executing the command using `sh -c "…"`.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is about `tr` but this is an equivalent alternative.

If you could write the `|tr ...` command,
it is much more clear (less confuse) to use `|sed -r 's"[\]"/"g'`.

I hope I can always avoid using `\\\\\\\\\\\...` I will never get used to it.